# Insert json data into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send data from a json file to a mysql database. I am first putting the data into an array and then sending to a sql Query but I am having some trouble making it work correctly. Here is my code.

```
$connect=mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');

IF (!$connect){
die ('Failed Connecting to Database: ' . mysql_error());}

  $json = file_get_contents('file.json');
  $data= json_decode($json);

  $array=array();


  foreach ($data->data->children as $postdata){
      $array['url'] = $postdata->data->url;
      $array['id'] = $postdata->data->id;

  };

  $columns = implode(",",  array_keys($array));
  $escaped_values = array_map('escape_string', array_values($array));
  $values = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
  $QUERY = "IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM mytable) IS NOT NULL)
            TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;

      INSERT INTO mytable ($columns) VALUES ($values)";

  mysql_query($QUERY);

  mysql_close($connect);
```

'
I am pretty new at this so this could be completely wrong but I was wondering if there are problems with this, or if there is a more efficient way to go about doing this.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not
>   supported) to the currently active database

You are sending 2 queries in 1 call and that is not supported.

Comment: Ok, I made that change. As far the passing of json data to the array variables, does it look correct to you?

Comment: If you split the queries and run them in 2 mysql_query statements it looks fine.