# Importing a JSON file into a database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have generated a JSON file and it is formatted correctly, the same way as I have export it from my MySQL database. Now I need to put it back:-)

I would like to read up on how to do this, so if there is a good link, I welcome it. I have used the phrase

> php - script to import JSON file into MySQL database

in Google and others like it, but I having no luck. 
Also if I import a file and the record already exists, how do I deal with duplicate issues? Can I make it so that it overwrites automatically?

I am uploading it from an iOS app, so I do not see the php file at work.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2007/10/inserting-an-array-into-a-mysql-database-table/ . You can json_decode your json into an array and then use the examples here. I Googled for "php import array into mysql". Lots of (in my eyes) useful hits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165456/import-json-file-into-mysql-database-with-php , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055130/insert-json-data-into-mysql-database-using-php ; I guess you need to work on your google skills too :)

Comment: Thanks, ill look into that - well it would have help if I knew I had to look for arrays in the search:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json_decode`

```
json_decode($json_from_ios_app, true)
```

`json_decode` will return associated array. Based from this structure, construct SQL queries.